# Can type inference be classified in two groups: unification-based and control-flow-based?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, type-theory, type-systems, type-inference

I recently came across the 1995 paper [Safety analysis versus type inference](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~palsberg/paper/ic95-ps.pdf) (pdf link) by Palsberg and Schartzbach that contrasts unification-based type inference and static analysis methods based on control-flow analysis. According to the paper:

- In unification based type inference each identifier is related to a type variable ranging over type schemes, such as $int$ and $\forall a b . a \rightarrow b$. In control-flow static analysis the identifiers get related to variables ranging over what primitive types and other values in the source program can flow into the identifier.
- Unification-based type inference is "local" and can be performed one module at a time. Control-flow analysis tends to be global and require the whole program to be analyzed at once.
- Damas-Milner unification is a linear time algorithm (for typical programs) while control-flow analysis tends to have worse case running times that are cubic or worse (and at least quadratic in practice).
- Control-flow analysis can reason about program safety more precisely than unification-based inference (for example, it can detect some instances of dead code)

My question is: is this classification complete or are there other kinds of type inference that they did not mention?

Comment: It's not clear to me that the two inference techniques are fundamentally different: it seems that in "unification based" inference the type-constraint resolution is deferred, whereas it is performed eagerly in the "control-flow based" approach.

Comment: @cody: What do you mean by "eager" there? In my head deferring type checking means doing runtime tests but thats clearly not what you were talking about.

Comment: I would say that there are also constraint-based approaches (the work of Scott Smith, for instance), though again the boundary with the other types is not clear cut.

Comment: @DaveClarke I think the constraint approach may fall under the "flow based" category: From the [webpage of Scott's research group](http://pl.cs.jhu.edu/constraints.shtml): "Type constraint systems are a very expressive form of type which can be given to programs. They are so expressive that they can in fact fully record flow information about a program, namely this data value could flow to that operation."

Comment: It' your classification. If that's the way you want to see it.

Comment: "Eager" in this context means that each constraint is solved (as much as possible) as soon as it is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps an even better way to see type inference is as a specialization of a single framework: [Abstract Interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) (abbreviated AI).  The hallmark of most unification-based type inference algorithms is that they generate the [principal type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_type) for a term; translated into AI terms, this means that you never need to **widen**, nor do you need to go to *power domains* to find the answer.  Unification turns out to be the 'join' operation -- there is also a nice categorical interpretation of unification which is even more enlightening.

Several comments shed light on this as well: all algorithms can be better understood in terms of generating then solving systems of constraints.  Unification is indeed eager, and constraint-solving (and that includes control-flow based approaches) tend to be lazier.

Perhaps an even better way to see type inference is as an alternate *interpreter* for a program: rather than producing values, it produces types.  It is very easy to see type inference as a form a *partial evaluation*.  Perhaps an easy introduction to that circle of ideas is via Aaron Stump's [A rewriting view of simple typing](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~astump/papers/lmcs12-rewriting-view.pdf).

Comment: Do you have a reference for the categorical interpretation of unification?

Comment: @cody: I first learned of it in Rydeheard and Burstall's *computational category theory* book, now available online at http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~david/categories/.